# Why does this regular expression fail with PCRE (PHP < 7.3) but works with PCRE2 (PHP >= 7.3)

Tags: php, regex, php-7.2, php-7.3

The regular expression:

```regex
/(?<nn>(?!und)[^\/,&;]+)(?:,\s?+)(?<vn>(?1))(?:\/|&|;|und|$)\s?/
```

is supposed to result in two matches using `preg_match_all`

```
nn(1): Oidtmann-van Beek
vn(1): Jeanne 

nn(2): Oidtmann
vn(2): Peter
```

On the sample string `Oidtmann-van Beek, Jeanne und Oidtmann, Peter`

This works with PCRE2 (PHP >= 7.3).

But not with PHP < 7.3, why?

https://regex101.com/r/zotHZN/1/

Comment: I think a more precise pattern like `/\b(?<nn>(?!und\b)\w+(?:[-'\s]+(?!und\b)\w+)*),\s?(?<vn>(?&nn))\b/u` would be better. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YhURns/1/).

Comment: Hard to tell without a sample string to test with. One interesting thing I see is in this group: `(?:,\s?+)` — I’m not sure what php will make of `\s?+` (one or more _optional_ whitespace). I would try `\s*` instead (zero or more whitespace). That might make slightly more sense to the PCRE compiler.

Comment: @rickdenhaan `\s?+` matches 1 or 0 whtespaces, it is a valid pattern in both PCRE and PCRE2.

Comment: The reason is that in PCRE2 the subroutine patterns are not atomic and can be backtracked into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not get the expected output with PCRE because the `(?1)` regex subroutine is atomic, and its pattern cannot be backtracked into.

See ["*Differences in recursion processing between PCRE2 and Perl*"](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#SEC21):

> Before release 10.30, recursion processing in PCRE2 differed from Perl in that a recursive subroutine call was always treated as an atomic group. That is, once it had matched some of the subject string, it was never re-entered, even if it contained untried alternatives and there was a subsequent matching failure. (Historical note: PCRE implemented recursion before Perl did.)
>
> Starting with release 10.30, recursive subroutine calls are no longer treated as atomic. That is, they can be re-entered to try unused alternatives if there is a matching failure later in the pattern. This is now compatible with the way Perl works. If you want a subroutine call to be atomic, you must explicitly enclose it in an atomic group.

So, the solution is to use the pattern itself, not the subroutine:

```php
/(?<nn>(?!und)[^\/,&;]+),\s?+(?<vn>(?!und)[^\/,&;]+)(?:\/|&|;|und|$)\s?/
```

Note I replaced `(?:,\s?+)` with just `\s?+` as the non-capturing group is redundant here.

I think a more precise pattern like `/\b(?<nn>(?!und\b)\w+(?:[-'\s]+(?!und\b)\w+)*),\s?(?<vn>(?&nn))\b/u` would be better here. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YhURns/1/). It will not require any backtracking as  the `\w+(?:[-'\s]+(?!und\b)\w+)*` part does not overlap with the `,\s?` pattern.